# select all rows with column value starting with "string..." in r

Tags: r, select, row, filtering, subset

This question is based on the mpg dataset built into R.

Here is a subset of the trans column: `"auto(l5)"   "manual(m5)" "manual(m6)" "auto(av)"   "auto(l5)"   "manual(m5)" "auto(av)"   "manual(m5)" "auto(l5)"   "manual(m6)" "auto(s6)"   "auto(l5)"   "manual(m5)" "auto(s6)"   "manual(m6)" "auto(l5)"`

What I need to do is select all the rows where the trans column value starts with "auto" regardless of what is in the parentheses. My output should be: `"auto(15)" "auto(av)" "auto(15) "auto(av)" "auto(15)" "auto(s6)" "auto(15)" "auto(s6)" "auto(15)"`

How do I do this?

Comment: df <- data.frame(data = c("auto(l5)", "manual(m5)" ,
                         "manual(m6)", "auto(av)", 
                         "auto(l5)", "manual(m5)", 
                         "auto(av)" ,"manual(m5)" ,
                         "auto(l5)", "manual(m6)" ,
                         "auto(s6)" ,"auto(l5)",
                         "manual(m5)", "auto(s6)", 
                         "manual(m6)" ,"auto(l5)"
                         ))
df <- df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(data, 'auto'))

Comment: Susan I tried your solution and got the following error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables

Comment: Is the error with the sample that I provided in the comments or with your actual data? If with your actual data, could be an inconsistent data type in your dataset?

Comment: Susan the error is with the data frame you provided. I can reproduce the creation of the data frame but the line df <- df %>% filter(str_detect(data, 'auto')) won't run, it produces the error noted above

Comment: have you loaded library(tidyverse)? and added a line break in your ide?

Comment: Susan thank you I did not load library(tidyverse) before but I just did and your solution worked. Note to all R coders: make sure you have the right packages installed and loaded.